# Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios5, twitter, linker-errors

I am trying to integrate Twitter into my app, and keep getting the following errors. 
Thanks for your help.

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTweetComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PreviewViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 7):

Did you add Twitter.framework ?

Comment: In fact, that was the problem. I did add the Twitter framework, but I needed to drag and drop it to the Link Binary With Libraries section under "Build Phases". So the framework was not correctly added to my project until now. Thanks for your help!